# An example of when we need yes command

Tags: command-line

What is the usage of yes command. I follow the [`man yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) also I try that but I want to know when we need to use this command. You can follow man page to know the usage of `yes`. But I am looking for a time when we need that? In which situation I need example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"yes" was created to allow automation of tasks that request confirmation. If you have a program that wants you to tell it "y" before it does something, you can now automate that program by piping yes into it.

Example :

```
yes | rm -i *.txt
```

Here yes is piped for confirmation to delete all txt files in the directory .

Another option print a string repeatedly :

```
yes "test"
```

Stop by <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>

It also can be used to say no , this repeat n after the rm :

```
yes n | rm -i *.txt
```

The above example says not to remove a file when rm -i prompts to remove the file.

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29) has a good explanation.

Basically it spams a "yes" to wherever it is run. This can be used to automate responses to programs that ask for user verification. As an example, the following:

```
rm -f *.txt
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
yes | rm *.txt
```

It pipes the "yes" to `rm`, so to any question that `rm` asks (write protection or similar), it will immediately get a "yes" and continue.

Common programs like `apt` or `rm` have a "force" function built in, but other programs may not. This is where `yes` can be useful.

It can also be used as input to create a certain size of file, or to stress test a system.