# Is there a way to run a bash script unattended?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm still pretty new to the Linux world now that I've completely the made the switch because of my experiences with Windows 10.  I gave it a shot, but it's just not as good as I would have expected due to all the hype around it. Anyway I would gauge my knowledge of Linux so far I'd say that I'm a little past KUbuntu as a "n00b" and "beginner". I'm not certain if this can be done, so I hope someone will let me know if this is possible or not.

I have already learned the `apt-get install -y Foo` trick to install whatever I'm trying to without the terminal asking me to hit `Y` or `N`.

So here's my question.  I have found many "post install" scripts for every flavor of Ubuntu as well as many for other distros like Elementary, Manjaro, SuSe, and so on. They have been made so others can install many pieces of software, tweaks, themes, etc.

Is it possible to tell my new Kubuntu 15.04 system to always hit Y when prompted to accept the new features?  Is there a way to do this with a bash script? Or do I have to watch it like a hawk so it does not keep aborting if I'm late getting to the computer to hit Y?

Comment: It may be worth looking into the usage of the `yes` command, which can be used to echo a 'y' followed by a newline repeatedly. There's an answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/459079/an-example-of-when-we-need-yes-command though I'm not 100% sure whether it's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. There's the `yes` command whose job is precisely that. It will repeatedly output a given string (`y` is the default). So, if the sciprt `foo.sh` expects you to hit <kbd>y</kbd> to confirm an action, you can run it this way:

```
yes | foo.sh
```

However, this is really not a good idea. First of all, in most cases, there is no timeout. You don't need to rush to the computer, it will wait for you. Computers tend to be quite patient beasts. More importantly, you rarely want to just blindly accept anything you are told to. It is a good idea to make up your own mind and that's why you're being asked.

In any case, the choice is yours. If you are sure you want to blindly answer "yes" to all questions, just use `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of the script and run `sed -i 's|apt-get install|apt-get -y --force-yes install|g' /path/to/script`, which would replace every occurrence of `apt-get install` with an automatically answered version. Be careful about the `--force-yes`, though.

Also this probably won't really solve your problem, because in most scripts Y/N questions are not "asked" by apt, but "by the script itself", usually with the `read` command.

You could try to run `/path/to/script -h` or `/path/to/script --help` to see if there is an auto-accept switch.

Another method would be to pass the "Y" via pipe, i.e. `for i in {1..10}; do echo Y; done |/path/to/script`, but that's a rather unclean method.

Answer (score 0):

- AFAIK, <kbd>Y</kbd> always is not good and more specifically with `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Actually, it is easy to answer Y for the 1st question before start downloading.
- The other ones are mainly from post install script, try this:

  ```
  sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install Foo
  ```

  **Source:** [How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps)

Comment: I don't think apt post-install scripts are meant.^^

Comment: Thank you @David, I just guess. the OP is new. Let's see what he is up to.